# Is there a Relationship between sum and sum of reciprocals?

Tags: summation

Is there any relationship between the sum of positive numbers and the sum of the reciprocals of the same numbers? For example:

$A=1+2+3.5$ and $B=1+1/2+ 10/35$

Thanks!

Comment: You can get a minimum value of $B$ in terms of $A$. but $B$ can be any value above that minimum.

Comment: Do you know how many terms there are in the sum?

Comment: *A* is *n* times the arithmetic mean, and *B* is the number of terms divided through the harmonic mean.

Comment: There are N terms in the sum.