# If $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ge a$, then what can we know about $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose that $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ge a$$
where $a>0$ and $x_i\in (0, b]$ for all $i$. Are there any bounding inequalities we can determine for $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i}?$$
I understand that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i} \ge \frac{n}{b}$, but I'm hoping to have some restriction that utilizes $a$.
I have found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917912/lower-bound-for-sum-of-reciprocals-of-positive-real-numbers) that starts with the knowledge that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = a$. Following the details of the explanation in that question, I eventually conclude that $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i} \ge \frac{n^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i},$$
but I'm not sure that this allows me to utilize the initial inequality $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ge a$. Am I missing something?

Comment: what is the range of $x_i$?

Comment: Are $x_i$ positive?

Comment: If $n \geq 2$ you can't say anything (why?).

Comment: Note that in the question you link to, it is assumed that all summands are positive.  That sort of detail is critical.  Did you mean to add that assumption?

Comment: Yes, all the $x_i$ are positive.

Comment: there is no lower bound as you can make $x_i$'s as large as you want. There is no upper bound since you can make at least one $x_i$ as small (positive) as you want.

Comment: @dezdichado I've edited the question. After some thought, I've determined that $x_i \in (0,b] \quad \forall i$ for some constant $b$.

Comment: @BSplitter if $x_i \in (0,b]$ then the supremum is $+\infty$ and the maximum can be never reached (just take $x_1  \to 0$). The minimum is equal to $n/b$ and occurs if and only if $x_i = b$. If you want to " have some restriction that utilizes $a$" then you may impose that $x_i \in [c,d]$  for example